# Add custom type typescript 3

Tags: typescript, types

The current behavior: I migrated from @types/openlayers": "4.6.17" to "@types/ol": "5.3.6" and I don't find the function getVectorContext(event) in ol/render so I added it manually to render.d.ts but the next npm install I will lose this modification

The wanted behavior: I want to add a file *.d.ts that contain a custom types to my project but I got the error :module not found can t resolve '/pathCustomTypes'

Answer (score 0):

You do not need `@types/openlayers` or `@types/ol`, just use the `ol` package. Then do:

```
import { getVectorContext } from 'ol/render';
```

**Edit:**

I am not really sure about your comment. However, if you open the *README.md* in *node_modules/ol* you can read:

> The `ol` package contains a `src/` folder with JSDoc annotated
>   sources. TypeScript can get type definitions from these sources with a
>   `jsconfig.json` config file in the project root:
>
> ```
> "compilerOptions": {
>     "checkJs": true,
>     // Point to the JSDoc typed sources when using modules from the ol package
>     "baseUrl": "./",
>     "paths": {
>       "ol": ["node_modules/ol/src"],
>       "ol/*": ["node_modules/ol/src/*"]
>     }   },   "include": [
>     "**/*.js",
>     "node_modules/ol/**/*.js"   ] }
> ```
>
> Project template with this configuration: https://gist.github.com/9a7253cb4712e8bf38d75d8ac898e36c.
>
> Note that the above only works when authoring in plain JavaScript. For
>   similar configurations with a `tsconfig.json` in TypeScript projects,
>   your mileage may vary.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and your solution work but the problem that we don t have the advantage of working by typescript all types is any'; so I don't understand how that's work and how the compiler know the ol lib and  and I m asking if we can profit of typing and work with ol 6.

Comment: @Ayoub You are welcome :) Feel free to accept my answer.